# Query to validate if items exist in partition group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a set of data that resembles the following format.

```
GROUP | ELEMENT
---------------
  1   |   A
  1   |   B
  1   |   C
  2   |   A
  3   |   B
  4   |   A
  4   |   B
  5   |   A
  5   |   C
```

I'd like to be able to verify that both elements A AND B exist in each of the groups.  Ideally I would return only those groups that have both elements.  In the example above I would like to return only GROUP 1 and GROUP 4.

EDIT:
Sorry I should have not implied that 'A' and 'B' were the only options.  Is it possible to look specifically for the existence of specific values such as 'A' and 'B'?  There may be other possible values.  I have updated the example data to reflect this.

Comment: can you show your original data?

Comment: Sorry, I should not have implied that the data was in another format.  This represents a subset of the original data returned from a simple select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a `Relational Division` problem but you need to display each individual `GROUP` with each `Element`.

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Query:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    TableName b
            WHERE   a."GROUP" = b."GROUP" AND
                    b."ELEMENT" IN ('A','B')
            GROUP   BY b."GROUP"
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d055/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════╦═════════╗
║ GROUP ║ ELEMENT ║
╠═══════╬═════════╣
║     1 ║ A       ║
║     1 ║ B       ║
║     1 ║ C       ║
║     4 ║ A       ║
║     4 ║ B       ║
╚═══════╩═════════╝
```

But if you want only to return `GROUP`, you can simply use this below

```
SELECT  "GROUP"
FROM    TableName b
WHERE   "ELEMENT" IN ('A','B')
GROUP   BY "GROUP"
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d055/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════╗
║ GROUP ║
╠═══════╣
║     1 ║
║     4 ║
╚═══════╝
```

Comment: Wouldn't simply do a count(*) also return a result if there were two entries and both contained an 'A' element, for example?  As I indicated I'd like to be sure that both elements are included.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether the following work but you can give a try

```
SELECT group, COUNT(DISTINCT(element))
FROM table
group by group
having COUNT(DISTINCT(element)) = 2
```

I am not sure whether `COUNT(DISTINCT(element))` will work!

Comment: +1 . . . Yes this will work, although the parentheses around element are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return all GROUP (IDs) and ELEMENT (names) where for each GROUP there are exactly 2 different elements. Change `HAVING` clause to amend "exactly 2 different ELEMENTS" rule.

```
SELECT GROUP, ELEMENT 
FROM MyTable
WHERE GROUP in 
    (SELECT GROUP from MyTable
     GROUP BY GROUP 
     HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT ELEMENT)=2
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> SELECT ID,
>        ELEMENT FROM STACK WHERE ID IN
>     (SELECT ID
>      FROM
>        (SELECT id AS ID,
>                COUNT(DISTINCT(element)) AS B
>         FROM STACK
>         WHERE ELEMENT IN ('A',
>                           'B')
>         GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(element)) >1)A)   AND ELEMENT IN ('A',
>                   'B');
```

** **id** is the **column** *group* in the question and *table* name is **stack**

If we remove the "ELEMENT IN" condition we will be able to get all the groups which has got more than one element

Answer (score 0):

It returns group only have elements A AND B

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table a
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table b
    WHERE a.group = b.group
    GROUP BY b.group
   HAVING COUNT(distinct element) = 2
)
and a.element IN ('A','B')
```